# Javascript UTC timestamp to Local Timezone

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert a timestamp being returned from a JSON resource in javascript that is displaying in UTC to the users local timezone. Below i'm trying to adjust with the user offset.

**Example UTC output for date:**
Tue Mar 27 2012 02:29:15 GMT-0400 (EDT)

Code

```
var date = new Date(data.date_created); //Data.date_created coming from json payload
var offset = date.getTimezoneOffset() //Get offset
var new_date = new Date(date  offset); //Add offset to userdate
```

I'm struggling with the appropriate method to achieve this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5):

I might be missing something but

```
var date = new Date( data.date_created );
```

does what I think you want.

```
>>> d=new Date('Tue Mar 27 2012 02:29:15 GMT-0800')
Date {Tue Mar 27 2012 06:29:15 GMT-0400 (EDT)}
>>> d.toLocaleString()
"Tue Mar 27 06:29:15 2012"
>>> d=new Date('Tue Mar 27 2012 02:29:15 GMT+0300')
Date {Mon Mar 26 2012 19:29:15 GMT-0400 (EDT)}
>>> d.toLocaleString()
"Mon Mar 26 19:29:15 2012"
```

Note how changing the GMT offset from -8 to +3 changes the resulting time by 11 hours.

Comment: Parsing of non—standard strings is implemetation dependent. It's much better to manually parse strings.